why do some syntax trees not preserve the same order as the linear order of the original sentence?
from what I know, syntax trees preserve the linear order of the original sentence when the leafs are read from left to right
for example in this (Arabic) case:

"Yakun" appears in the sentence before the subject "mohammmed-u", yet in the tree from left to right it's read "lam mohammed-u yakun"
Is there any reason for this?
this is from the paper "Adverbs and adverbials in contemporary
Arabic syntax: A phase-based account"
